# bool saving problem

Tags: objective-c, ios4, audio, boolean, nsuserdefaults

**Edited**

i've got a sound in my app which begins to play when the app is started. further I've got two method to play and stop the sound:

```
-(void)playBgMusic {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgmusic" ofType:@"aif"];
theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];
[defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"isQuiet"]; }


 -(void)stopMusic {

[theAudio stop];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isQuiet"]; }
```

Now I've got different viewControllers and in my mainView there's a button which stops/starts the music (depends on wheter music is playing or not).

So I've got:

```
-(IBAction)check {

isquiet = [defaults boolForKey:@"isQuiet"];

if (isquiet == YES) {

    [self playBgMusic];

    // Change button to indicate music is playing

} 

else {

    [self stopMusic];

    // Change the button to indicate music has stopped...
}
```

}

Now there's a problem. The sound plays when the app is started, after that I can press the button and the sound is stopped but then I cant start it again. I've put NSLogs in the code and saw that the BOOL is still NO after pressing the stopButton.

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, strictly speaking, but hopefully it'll set you on the right track...

Add some logging (either via `NSLog(...)` or add logging breakpoints) to the NO and YES cases of the above code that outputs the value of `isquiet`. Then you can see which code paths are invoked when you press the button under different scenarios.

Comment: that's no answer indeed, you should have done this with comment. i tried this and it's allright. The bool has the value it should have all the time, i think the problem is on another point.

Comment: @Leon: You are absolutely right. This was an attempt to guide you towards a solution, which doesn't strictly fall under the definition of "answer". I was under the impression you wanted people to try to help you, and I thought this might actually solve your problem, but you are obviously more concerned that they follow the norms correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, the only thing missing is actually saving the bool value back to NSUserDefaults when you start/stop playing, so everytime you click the button and read it, you get the correct value.

Give this a try and see if it helps:

```
-(IBAction)check 
{
    BOOL isQuiet = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"isQuiet"];
    if (isQuiet)
    {
        [self playBgMusic];
        // Change button to indicate music is playing
    } else {
        [self stopBgMusic];
        // Change the button to indicate music has stopped...
    }
}
```

Then in your `playBgMusic` method, add the following:

```
[userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"isQuiet"];
```

And in your `spotBgMusic` method, add the following:

```
[userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isQuiet"];
```

Comment: still doesn't work but I got the problem, you can see it in my edited question